# How can a GWT served html page have the lang attribute set?

Tags: gwt, lang

As per GAR compliance, language has to be indicate with page.

```
Question 2.9. Is the content’s human language indicated in the markup?
E.g. for a page written in all one language, `<html lang="fr">`, or for a multi-lingual page,  `<div lang="fr">`.
```

A GWT application indicates its supported locales list in  in its gwt.xml, and the html page with the locale requested by the client gets served.
How can a GWT application have the lang attribute set in the html tag? 
Our application is UI widget based, and therefore we don't have a host html page, but directly add the widget to the RootPanel().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Document.get().getDocumentElement().setAttribute("lang",
     LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale().getLocaleName());
```

Comment: I tried that:
    HelloWorld helloWorld = new HelloWorld("abcd");    // HelloWorld is a ui widget.
    Document.get().getBody().appendChild(helloWorld.getElement());
    Document.get().getDocumentElement().setAttribute("lang",
        LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale().getLocaleName());

But when I go to the page source of the rendered page on the browser, there is no attribute in the html tag.

Comment: Try .setAttribute("lang", "fr"). Do you have the same result?

Comment: Ok, your answer was already correct. Page source in the browser did not show the lang attribute but saving the page as a file and opening it in an editor shows the attribute.